# Reusing 2d animation

Tags: animation

I designed a robot sprite and I have to make an idle animation, it's easy but the problem is that I need to reuse that idle animation with some other sprite, I've asked to my animation teacher and told me that this is only possible with 3d animation, is that true? And if there is some possibilty I can reuse a 2d animation behaviour, what program is the best to do it?

Pd: I use toon boom harmony and I'm trying brash monkey spriter too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on HOW you animated. If you animated things by drawing frame by frame, then no it can not be transferred. If however you have a rigged character than the animation will for obvious reasons move from rig to rig since they are either identical or can be made equivalent. No guarantees it will work well or easily though.

> my animation teacher and told me that this is only possible with 3d animation, is that true?

Depends on how you define 3D. For obvious reasons all 3D animation software are capable of doing 2D animation. So no its not entirely true, however probably true enough for a lie to children.

Simply the transferability is not dependent on the type of software used but rather do you depend on direct manipulation of data or indirect manipulation. Indirect manipulation means some sort of rig that can be shared across assets.

> what program is the best to do it?

Best is not defined. Its a optimization problem and i can not optimize with this info. Usually a tool you know how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement:

One program that specializes in this aspect of reusing the same animation for different characters is https://www.reallusion.com/cartoon-animator/2d-character-designers.html

And you could try some 3D programs and adjust the materials to make them 2D, like Blender.

Daz studio is also free and you can reuse the animations on different characters.